# Что за свойство в консоли разработчика?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Использую плагин emerge для анимации сайта и в консоли наблюдаю непонятное свойство "FIRED!".

Что это означает и как можно пофиксить это?
Для наглядности, что именно за свойство, прикрепил скриншот инспектора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не свойство. это простой текст в консоли.

Comment: Ищи в проекте, где такое выводится

Comment: Если переводить, то `Fired` означает что что-то (простите за тавтологию) было запущено / воспроизведено / сработано, в вашем случае, подозреваю что это либо какое-то событие на которое действует анимация, или может сама анимация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено:
Оказалось, что это внедрено разработчиком плагина.
Плагин сделан так, что не требует обращения именно к файлу JavaScript для инициализации.
Инициализация происходит путем добавления атрибутов плагина в самом html.
И в консоль выводится "FIRED!" при каждом обращении к плагину в HTML, что и мы и видим в консоли